# finding absolute error of approximated function - matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, approximation

During an experiment i registered several points. Thereafter I approximated them with 9th order polynomial. I need to find the absolute error of the measurements and the approximated function on y axis. Any idea?

*edit:

```
y = [0.006332 0.04056 0.11813 0.1776723 0.23840 0.29827 0.358396...   
0.418149 0.4786 0.478154 0.538114 0.53862 0.598954 0.659804...
0.720267 0.781026 0.8412 0.901548 0.962022 1.022567 1.083291...
1.143653 1.20449 1.14398 1.02273 0.962285 0.90203 0.841474...
0.780881 0.720346 0.659896 0.579599 0.539505 0.478662 0.418963...
0.35859 0.299039 0.238886 0.179108 0.118999 0.058841 0.006249...
0.06189];
x2 = linspace (1,43,43);
x2 = x2';
y = y';
f = fit(x2,y,'poly9');
figure()
plot(f,x2,y)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
y_fit = f(x2);
error = y - y_fit;

hold on
plot(x2, error)

% Several popular error norms:
norm(error, 1)
norm(error, 2)
norm(error, Inf)
```

Like `y`, the variable `error` is a vector.  If you want to reduce this vector to a single number, you can use one the norms.  [See this for more on error norms.](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node135.html)